# How do I upload a docker image to my organization

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have created a Organization in dockerhub. I need to upload my image into my organization where my team members can see and use it.

How to upload my image into my organization? anyone kindly help me on this

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#pushing-a-docker-container-image-to-docker-hub

Answer (score 1):

You need to tag your docker image with your org name

Then when you push that tag the image will be uploaded into the correct repo.

So for instance if you already have a local image `myImage` and you want to upload it into an org called `ourOrg` and a repo called `ourImage`

```
docker image tag myImage ourOrg/ourImage:v1
docker image push ourOrg/ourImage:v1
```

You will need to create `ourOrg` and then the `ourImage` repo before running these commands